# Is there a way to explicitly acknowledge message receipt with QuickFIX/J?

Tags: quickfix, quickfixj

For a guaranteed message receiver, in an ACK-based protocol like Apache Kafka, TIBCO EMS/RVCM, IBM MQ and JMS there is a way to explicitly acknowledge the receipt of a message. Explicit Acks are not just automatically sent when you return from a dispatcher's callback but an extra method on the session or message to say "I've processed this message". The reason for the existence of this **explicit** ack is that you can safely queue received messages to be processed by another thread at a later time and then only call this explicit-ack method once your are really done processing this message (safely storing to DB, forwarding to another MOM, etc.) Having this explicit method ensures that you are not losing messages even when you crash after receiving messages but didn't process them yet.

Now with QuickFIX/J (of FIX in general) I know it's not ACK-based but instead persists the last received SeqNum in a file and instead of sendings Acks, message guarantee is achieved by sending ResendRequests for missed SeqNums. But still, is there a way to tell the QuickFIX/J API "I don't automatically want you to persist this last SeqNum once I exit this onMessage() callback but hold off until I tell you so". In other words is there  a Session variation which doesn't persist SeqNums automatically and then I can call something on the FIX message to persist this last Seqnum once I've really processed/saved that message ?

(If this feature doesn't exist I think it would be a good addition to the API)

Comment: Off the top of my head I think you could implement a custom store that does not persist the seqnums.

Comment: Ok. And then have an extra method to write to this custom store ? Is there an interface exposed to write a custom store ?

Comment: Implement a `MessageStore`: https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/master/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/MessageStore.java. Implement https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj/blob/48ea859f55904643a9059b91b37611e4424c6248/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/MessageStore.java#L66 to do nothing and call another method later that will really increment the seqnums? That could work.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. And how do I register my MessageStore implementation ?

Comment: You pass it into your connector. Here is a short intro: https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj#creating-a-quickfixj-application

Comment: Do you think this will ever be a builtin feature of quickfix/J ? I've found the interfaces: interface MessageStore and MessageStoreFactory

Comment: I could only imagine that this would be a bultin feature if someone opened a pull request to add it. IIRC no-one ever asked for this feature so either it is very very rarely used or other people worked around it by themselves.